# Handling long running folder moves

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I'm calling the [folder move](https://developers.box.com/docs/#users-move-folder-into-another-folder) API call (via the Python SDK -- by extending the Client class) and am running into problems when the user content I'm trying to move takes a very long time or doesn't fully complete.

Any guidance on proper error handling or call status watching?  As it is now, the PUT call timed out in my script -- generating a traceback, but from the admin interface I can still see some progress is occurring in the background.  I'm trying to figure out how I could idempotently recover from this or increase the timeout to minimize the risk of it happening again.

Also, it seems at times that large moves only partially succeed leaving me with content split between the original and new folders.  Not fun to automatically clean up from.

Additional background: Am using the Python SDK to write some basic user cleanup routines:

1. Move a user's content to the Box Admin's account (if that user is 'Inactive').
2. Once content is moved, move the new folder underneath a "Separated User's" folder (also living under the Box Admin account).
3. Create a metadata file with some basic tracking info and store in the separated user's former folder.
4. Delete the original user's account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How large is folder you are attempting to move? If it is a very large folder (10+GBs) this could require a ticket with Box Support to run the job on the backend for you. You can reach Box support by sending an email to support@box.com.

Otherwise your strategy is correct.

Comment: Yes, in some cases the folder will be >10GB.  Not too uncommon, in fact.

Would be nice to see this become a "backgroundable" job.  SDK call returns a task ID which we can poll until completion, and some graceful failure scenario would occur so a portion of your data isn't orphaned.

I guess will provide this feedback to the Box team as an RFE. :-)